# Is it possible to play videos from a website other than YouTube on Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, youtube

I am developing a video sharing site.

As you know if you go to YouTube, copy a link, paste it on the Facebook wall or a message, and then you can play it on Facebook without going to YouTube. As far as I know YouTube is the only site that does that. If you copy a link from [Vimeo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimeo) for example and paste it on Facebook, it will be displayed as thumbnail and you won't be able to play it from Facebook.

So, is there an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) that I can use to play videos from my site on Facebook when a user share a link, or is this feature only available for YouTube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You need to host a web page that has the proper Open Graph Protocol meta tags for each video format you offer on a given video.

Then someone needs to share that URL on Facebook.  Facebook will crawl your website, parse the meta tags, and provide a video player.

Offering more video formats ensures better cross-browser compatibility.

Learn about the meta tags here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Use the Facebook debugger tool to make sure you are formatting your meta tags correctly: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: thank you!! i wounder why vimeo, metacafe, dailymotion and others don't do the same!

Comment: @Eli they probably want to drive traffic to their site, which won't happen if user watches video from w/in Facebook website.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is down to Facebook designing their systems so that when they see a YouTube URL, it embeds the video cleverly, meaning the user isn't redirected.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there an API that I can use to play videos from my site on Facebook when a user share a link

@Eli,

Yes there is an API to play videos from a website on facebook, it is called The Open Graph Protocol. Read all about it at: http://ogp.me/ Additional documentation can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Please find below some example code to get your started, enjoy.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en" class="no_js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Title goes here">
<meta property="og:type" content="company">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://yourdomainhere.com/">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourdomainhere.com/og_image_that_shows_on_facebook.jpg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site Name">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID_NUMBER_IF_YOU_HAVE_ONE">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="ADMIN_ID_NUMBER_FOR_FACEBOOK_ANALYTICS">
<meta property="og:description" content="Your description.">
<meta property="og:determiner" content="the" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/bond/trailer.swf" /><!--VIDEO SRC URL-->
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/movie.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
/*Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/*/
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  'use strict';

  FB.init({
    appId                 : 'APP_ID_GOES_HERE', //App ID
    channelURL            : '//yourdomainhere.com/channel.php', //Channel File
    status                : true, //Check login status
    cookie                : true, //Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml                 : true, //Parse XFBML
    oauth                 : true, //Enable OAuth 2.0
    login                 : true,
    authResponse          : true, //Object
    frictionlessRequests  : true
  });

//Additional initialization code here

};

/*Load the Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK Asynchronously */
(function(d){
  'use strict';

  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```